# How to feed a placeholder tensor without fixed shape?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

After some work, the question becomes: how to feed a placeholder tensor without fixed shape?  The code is as follows. Note that tensor 'x' has shape [?, 32, 32, 64]. Obviously, the shape of 'ini_obj' is wrong. So, how can I feed tensor 'x' in 'eval()' method.

```
ini_obj = np.random.random((None, 32, 32, 64))    # numpy array
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(x)
x.eval(feed_dict={x: ini_obj}, session=sess)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a tensor to numpy array, you have to run eval() function in keras.

Comment: I have tried : with tf.Session() as sess: arr = x.eval(sess). It says: TypeError: input must be a dictionary. Could you please be more specific? Thx

Comment: array = your_tensor.eval(session=your_session) , Can you paste your code?

Comment: I retrieve a tensor which has format (? 224,224,1), then use  tf.Session() as sess: arr = x.eval(sess) to try conversion. But it fails.

Comment: I guess the problem might be caused by '?'. Any idea on that?

Comment: When you want to run the session you have to feed dictionary with values, I am not seeing that you are running a session. You can run session with tensor.

Comment: ? indicates the batch size it is not problem with you can specify it at the run time.

Comment: For this tensor format, would you plz give a sample on how to run the session and how to feed the dict? Thx

Comment: https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html good example for your understanding.